# loop plotting a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

hi I have a Data frame char that consist of 9 columns and I want to plot each column separately I'm trying the following code but not getting any errors or output

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 5))  # Set up a 2 x 5       
plotting space          

for (i in char) { # Loop over loop.vector

ggplot(char, aes(char[[i]],
               fill = char[[i]])) +
geom_bar()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the output of `ggplot` in a list and then use any of the package which allows plotting multiple plots together specifying `nrow` and `ncol` value.

```
library(ggplot2)

result <- vector('list', ncol(char))
cols <- names(char)
for (i in seq_along(char)) { 
  result[[i]] <- ggplot(char, aes(.data[[cols[i]]], fill = .data[[cols[i]]])) +  
                 geom_bar()
}

patchwork::wrap_plots(result, nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
```